# set project specific ruby on rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I am currently learning how to use Ruby on Rails.

My local machine (Mac OS X Mavericks) is running Ruby 2.1.0 and Rails 4.

In order to follow a tutorial, I need it to run Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.

However, I do not want to downgrade my whole machine, but only the directory of the tutorial project.

All my project are located in **Desktop > work** and the project I would like to set up the specific environment is located in **Desktop > work > project_name**

I tried to install RVM and use .rvmrc project files, as described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-rvm-to-manage-ruby-installations-and-environments-on-a-vps), but could not achieve my goal.

What is the correct, step by step, workflow to set a project specific Ruby on Rails environment, in a given directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your gem file:

```
ruby "1.9.3"
gem 'rails', '3.2'
```

THEN

```
bundle install
```

THEN

```
rails s
```

**Now your environment will work as specify.**

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

I do know how to modify the Gem file, but then, what about dependents?

I mean, when I am going to add a new Gem, how can I make sure that it will work with my local versions?

Comment: adding this your environment will rails 3.2 and if some gems will not work then it will show error message , its not a big deal

Comment: Correct. I actually had other [other versioning problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599904/ruby-on-rails-mac-osx-mavericks-issues-after-rvm-install?noredirect=1#comment36227399_23599904) that are now solved.